# How to send email in HTML format

Tags: vba, outlook

I am using a suggestion by kmote from this answer (https://superuser.com/questions/635094/) to send a message.

I have images and text formatting in my body. The message is formatted to text mode. Is there any way to make it HTML format, so it would be the same as in my appointment?

```
Private Sub Application_Reminder(ByVal Item As Object)
  Dim objMsg As MailItem
  Set objMsg = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)

If Item.MessageClass <> "IPM.Appointment" Then
  Exit Sub
End If

If Item.Categories <> "Automated Email Sender" Then
  Exit Sub
End If

  objMsg.To = Item.Location
  objMsg.Subject = Item.Subject
  objMsg.Body = Item.Body
  objMsg.Send

  Set objMsg = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Set the BodyFormat: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.bodyformat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.Body is the text body.  If you want to copy the Html body try:

```
objMsg.HtmlBody = Item.HtmlBody
```

Comment: Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method.

Comment: @user7202022.  `objMsg` is a mail item which definitely has a Html body.  What is `Item`?

Comment: that's correct `objMsg.HtmlBody = Item.Body` works. Item is Appointment where Body is taken. I guess appointment does not have HTML body version? That's why it does not work?

Comment: @user7202022 Since my last comment, I saw than `Item` is a `IPM.Appointment`.  I cannot find any useful documentation on this class.  If I understand your comment correctly, `Item.Body` is an Html string.  You are correct, an `AppointmentItem` only has a text body but since both bodies are strings, you can put an Html string in the text body.  Have you got what you want or is `Item.Body` not the formatted body you want for your message?